# Apache Tomcat URI Encoding - UTF-8

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat, servlets, utf-8

When I attempted to run an application in the development environment to pass Arabic values in the request URL, it worked correctly.

I was able to get the correct text in the JSP file.

But when I deployed the same content in the Apache web server, Arabic values are displayed as:

```
?????????
```

**How can I resolve this?**

I have already set the URIEncoding to UTF-8 in server.xml and enabled the character encoding filters in conf/WEB.xml.

Comment: Is it about `Apache HTTP Server` OR `Apache Tomcat`?

Comment: Even when i  try bypassing apache HTTP and directly access the application via port 8080 same ???? is displayed

Comment: Please show the relevant code (JSP and Filter snippets)...

Answer (score 1):

Change the `URIEncoding` of the [`Connector`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add -Dfile.encoding="utf-8" in your catalina.bat

```
_EXECJAVA% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% -Djava.endorsed.dirs="%JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS%" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" -Dcatalina.base="%CATALINA_BASE%" -Dcatalina.home="%CATALINA_HOME%" `-Dfile.encoding="utf-8`" -Djava.io.tmpdir="%CATALINA_TMPDIR%" %MAINCLASS% %CMD_LINE_ARGS% %ACTION%
```